# How do I export a Python dataframe to an excel file with a form containing dropdown menus, a date picker and checkboxes?

Tags: excel, openpyxl, export-to-excel

I have done some data analysis in Python, but management needs the output in excel. The output needs to be an interactive form where the user can select values from dropdown menus, select a date using a date picker and contain checkboxes to communicate binary states.

For example, I want a form like this:

[image]

I then want to have a calculate button that then looks up all relevant data from my dataframe (which I can copy/paste in a second tab as a data backend) and output a calculation based on the corresponding data.

Here is the catch: Since I need to update the data backend very often and data analysis is conduced in Python, I want to generate the excel sheet using Python code. If it is not possible to generate a form with dropdowns, radio buttons etc. using Python, I can create this in excel, but then populate the data backend tab using Python.

How would I approach this?